# Set value property of Choisebox from objects out of db

Tags: java, javafx

How can I set the property value of an object for the display of a choicebox?

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<LuggageBrand> brandSelector;
```

Here you can see that I am filling the choicebox with `LuggageBrand` objects, but now the value that is being shown on the application are the `.toString()` of the object.

How can I say, hey, please use this property to show on the choicebox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the converter on the `ChoiceBox`:

```
public void initialize() {

    brandSelector.setConverter(new StringConverter<LuggageBrand>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(LuggageBrand luggageBrand) {
            // whatever logic you need here to turn the LuggageBrand object to a string:
            String value = luggageBrand.getXXX();
            return value ;
        }

        @Override
        public LuggageBrand fromString(String text) {
            // this method is not used by the ChoiceBox, so you can just
            return null ;
        }
    });

    // other initialization code...

}
```